# How do I swap values of records in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm supposed to flip flight numbers for pairs of flights going back and forth from a set of cities, so for example:

1439 ATL SFO
1440 SFO ATL

would end up as:

1440 ATL SFO
1439 SFO ATL

I tried this query (because you can't UPDATE .. JOIN in Oracle):

```
UPDATE
   (SELECT f.airline, f.flightno flightno_f, d.airline, d.flightno flightno_d
       FROM flights f
       INNER JOIN flights d ON f.airline = 9 AND
         f.sourceairport = d.destairport AND
         f.destairport = d.sourceairport AND d.airline = 9
       WHERE d.flightno < f.flightno) g
   SET g.flightno_f = g.flightno_d,
     g.flightno_d = g.flightno_f;
```

where airline, flightno is the primary key for table flights. The select gives me the correct set of records that I want to swap on, but the UPDATE... SET gives me this error:

```
   SET g.flightno_f = g.flightno_d,
       *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @therin Try adding constraint alter table flights add constraint flights_uk unique(flightno);

Comment: Add a constraint to the view g I've created? I'm not sure what you mean. I've tried adding another constraint to the flights table, but one of the other main problems I've been dealing with is that I can't add a unique constraint on just flight number, there could be an identical flight number for another airline.

Comment: @therin That's the problem you are facing since you have identical flight number it is not able to update

Comment: @Sam: it is one of the required steps. But another step is to write a query (the nested select one) that returns unambiguous result set.

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but when I actually perform the query there are _no_ duplicate flight numbers because I filter all of them out. Is there any manual way to get around this?

Comment: @therin: is flight number covered with unique constraint?

Comment: no, that is not possible because there could be another airline with the same flight number. However, because I am filtering out every airline but one, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: and the primary key is (airline, flightno)

Comment: @therin refer http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2009/01/ora-01779-cannot-modify-column-which.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to update a join, it doesn't matter that the dataset you are selecting happens to be effectively key-preserved; Oracle has to be able to see from the constraints and the predicates that it will by definition be key-preserved.  And because you have an inequality condition on the flightnumber, there is nothing in the data definition to guarantee that you won't have multiple matches for a given source row.

If it's guaranteed that the flight numbers will always differ by 1, you might be able to use the join method if you change the condition to `d.flightno + 1 = f.flightno`.

In any case, I think the following will work ... because of statement-level read-consistency the subquery should return correct results even as the rows are updated.

```
UPDATE flights f1
  SET flightno =
    (SELECT flightno
       FROM flights f2
       WHERE f2.airline = f1.airline
         AND f2.sourceairport = f1.destairport
         AND f2.destairport = f1.sourceairport
    )
  WHERE airline = 9;
```